# Get Full Class Property "Tree" Name as String

Tags: c#, .net, properties, linq-expressions

What I am trying to do is probably a little strange.
But **I am trying to** (this is the best I can explain it) use reflection to get a full class property tree name as a string.

---

**Successful example** so far:

By using expressions I am able to convert:

```
() => Model.Cargo.Id
```

into the string:

```
"Model.Cargo.Id"
```

---

**My problem now is** when I am using an array in the mix, I do not get the array name. All I get is the last properties name.

**Unsuccessful example**:

```
Model.CargoTasks[j].IsSet
```

Only returns me the string:

```
"IsSet"
```

**Ideally** I want the following string result:

```
"Model.CargoTasks[0].IsSet"
```

I am probably asking a little much to get the index included in the result, but it would be fantasic if this were possible.

---

**The code I am using** to process these examples is as follows:

```
public static string ToMemberAccess<TResult>(this Expression<Func<TResult>> expression)
{
    // Get the body of the expression
    Expression body = expression.Body;
    if (body.NodeType != ExpressionType.MemberAccess && body.NodeType != ExpressionType.Convert)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Property expression must be of the form '() => SomeProperty'", "expression");
    }

    var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression ?? ((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;
    var stuff = GetMemberNames(memberExpression);
    stuff.Reverse();

    return string.Join(".", stuff);
}

static List<string> GetMemberNames(MemberExpression expression,  List<string> actual = null)
{
    if (actual == null) actual = new List<string>();

    var member = expression.Member;
    var subExp = expression.Expression as MemberExpression;
    actual.Add(member.Name);

    if(subExp != null) actual = GetMemberNames(subExp, actual);

    return actual;
}
```

**Thanks** in advance! Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the response.
However, I have tested this it returns something more like: `Model.CargoTasks.get_Item(value(Resources.AssignTasks.AssignTasks+<>c__DisplayClass5).j).IsSet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value in the indexer, you must compile and execute the expression - which is **prohibitively expensive**, but it can be done using a modified version of `ExpressionStringBuilder`. Note that I've added a parameter, `compileConstants`. When it's set to `false`, the output will be something like `Model.CargoTasks[_.j].IsSet`.

Note that this sample visitor is incomplete (i.e. it doesn't support all kinds of expressions). You can complement it using the [code in GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Linq/Expressions/ExpressionStringBuilder.cs).

```
public static string ToMemberAccess<TResult>(Expression<Func<TResult>> expression, bool compileConstants = false)
{
    var builder = new ExpressionStringBuilder(compileConstants);
    builder.Visit(expression);
    return builder.ToString();
}

internal class ExpressionStringBuilder : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly bool _compileConstants;
    private readonly StringBuilder _out;

    public ExpressionStringBuilder(bool compileConstants)
    {
        _compileConstants = compileConstants;
        _out = new StringBuilder();
    }

    protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Value != null)
        {
            string text = node.Value.ToString();
            if (node.Value is string)
            {
                Out("\"");
                Out(text);
                Out("\"");
            }
            else if (text == node.Value.GetType().ToString())
            {
                Out('_');
            }
            else
            {
                Out(text);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Out("null");
        }
        return node;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        int num = 0;
        Expression expression = node.Object;
        if (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(node.Method, typeof(ExtensionAttribute)) != null)
        {
            num = 1;
            expression = node.Arguments[0];
        }
        var name = node.Method.Name;
        var isIndexer = name == "get_Item";
        if (expression != null)
        {
            Visit(expression);
            if (!isIndexer)
            {
                Out('.');
            }
        }
        if (isIndexer)
            Out('[');
        else
        {
            Out(name);
            Out('(');
        }
        int i = num;
        int count = node.Arguments.Count;
        while (i < count)
        {
            if (i > num)
            {
                Out(", ");
            }
            VisitArgument(node.Arguments[i]);
            i++;
        }
        Out(isIndexer ? ']' : ')');
        return node;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitIndex(IndexExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Object != null)
        {
            Visit(node.Object);
        }
        else
        {
            Out(node.Indexer.DeclaringType.Name);
        }
        if (node.Indexer != null)
        {
            Out(".");
            Out(node.Indexer.Name);
        }

        Out('[');
        for (var index = 0; index < node.Arguments.Count; index++)
        {
            if (index > 0)
            {
                Out(", ");
            }
            var expression = node.Arguments[index];
            VisitArgument(expression);
        }
        Out(']');
        return node;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
    {
        Visit(node.Body);
        return node;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        OutMember(node.Expression, node.Member);
        return node;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _out.ToString();
    }

    private void VisitArgument(Expression expression)
    {
        if (_compileConstants)
        {
            // TODO: possibly check the expression is not dependent on parameters
            var value = Expression.Lambda(expression).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
            Out(value + string.Empty);

        }
        else
        {
            VisitArgument(expression);
        }
    }

    private void OutMember(Expression instance, MemberInfo member)
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            Visit(instance);
            if (_out.Length > 0)
                Out('.');
            Out(member.Name);
            return;
        }
        Out(member.DeclaringType.Name + "." + member.Name);
    }

    private void Out(char c)
    {
        _out.Append(c);
    }

    private void Out(string s)
    {
        _out.Append(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!
This works great.